# How to switch a button click event sender from code behind to MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, events, mvvm

I have a button with its Click event on the code-behind, something like this:

```
private void ButtonManager_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        var addButton = sender as FrameworkElement;
    }
```

In case I move to MVVM and no code-behind, I use a Command class with Execute, something like this:

```
public override void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
      // sender?
    }
```

How should I manage the "sender as.." that was used in code-behind?

Comment: Why would you need the sender in MVVM? A view model does not know any view elements. You may pass data to the `parameter` argument via the Button's `CommandParameter` property.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `CommandParameter` to bind the control to itself.
but it's not a good idea to send the ViewComponent to ViewModel and change it. because in MVVM, the View shouldn't know anything about View. If you want to change anything in View, you can define properties in ViewModel and bind them to view separately.
Any way, the solution for your question is in the code below but I **don't suggest it**:

**Sample Code**

**Xaml:**

```
<Button Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=.}"/>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private void Execute(object? obj)
{
   var sender = obj as FrameworkElement;
}
```

Comment: This is not MVVM. You are passing a view element to the view model. In order to distinguish different Buttons, you could simply pass some ID to the CommandParameter like `CommandParameter="Save"`.

Comment: yes I mention it on the answer, that is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks to all for comments, the suggested approach is working and I agree with you it may not be the best solution. Every further solution is welcome

Comment: @bighunter without knowing why you need to access the control from the viewmodel there will be no further solution you may welcome